# Rich Text Editor in CQ5 for touch UI

Tags: aem, rich-text-editor

The rich text editor in AEM 6 has a source code editor, which renders the html code if copy pasted in it. Am stuck with the JS part. how to make the script tag work in it?

If i add

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){ //alert("1"); });
</script>
```

then it converts it to:

```
<p>$(document).ready(function(){ //alert(&quot;1&quot;);</p>
```

when viewed in the page source.

and " $(document).ready(function(){ //alert("1"); });"  is rendered on the page as it is.

Comment: What do you mean by stuck ? what happens when you add script tags in them ? you get javascript errors on your debugger console ?

Comment: it automatically removes the <script> tags once you reclick the source editor to view your preview.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to overlay two files by creating corresponding structure in /apps:

- /libs/cq/ui/rte/core/WhitespaceProcessor.js
- /libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/form/rte/WhitespaceProcessor.js

and modify DEFAULT_REMOVAL_RULES array at the bottom of each file - there is a list of tags which RTE widget removes from the HTML source code.

Comment: I could not find /libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/form/rte/WhitespaceProcessor.js file instead i found /etc/clientlibs/granite/coralui2/optional/rte/js/core/WhitespaceProcessor.js because I need it for touch UI and modified the DEFAULT_REMOVAL_RULES  to true. Changes which occurred were I wrote script in the source code as  : <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("1");});
</script> which was rendered as it on the page like : $(document).ready(function(){
alert("1");});..... It is not working

Comment: Ok, I see, I'm on AEM 5.6.1 and your version is using different version of Coral UI, that's why scripts are sitting elsewhere. Can you probably copy/paste content of original WhitespaceProcessor.js somewhere (e.g. http://pastebin.com/) so I can check the code?